# How do I rotate the whole web page 90, 180 or 270 degrees?

Tags: html, css, rotation

I want to rotate the whole web page 90, 180 or 280 degrees.

Solution how to rotate 90 degrees is given in answer
[Rotate all html element (whole page) 90 degree with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856013/rotate-all-html-element-whole-page-90-degree-with-css) . If I change 90 degrees to 270 degrees web page rotates "out of the screen" or is not centered to the screen. I would like to rotate the page like I rotate my monitor. My page starts from top left.

How to edit this code to properly work with 180 and 270 degrees?

```
.wrapper{
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin:bottom left;

    position:absolute;
    top:-100vw;

    height:100vw;
    width:100vh;

    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;

    overflow:auto;
}
```

Comment: if you dont change the transform-origin does it work like you want?

Comment: You have in your CSS six lines, think why there are there. Note: changing background/color has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

`transform-origin` is the CSS property responsible for this. It determins the point the element is rotated around of. If you change the `transform-origin` and rotate the element, the position of the element can change depending on what value you use. You can change the value of `transform-origin` to the result you need.

Here's an example of two different `transform-origin`s (hover on them):

```css
.wrapper {
  margin-left: 50px;
  color: white;
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.spacerM {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both;
  height: 30px;
}

.correct {
  transform-origin: center;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">Transform-Origin Bottom Left</div>
<div class="spacerM"></div>
<div class="wrapper correct">Transform-Origin Center</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856013/rotate-all-html-element-whole-page-90-degree-with-css) mentioned above, I was able to get 90, 180, and 270 degree page rotation working with the following styles.  `transform-origin` and `top` are needed for 90 and 270 but not for 180.

```css
// 90 degrees
.wrapper {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: bottom left;
  top: -100vw;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}

// 180 degrees
.wrapper {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: absolute;
}

// 270 degrees
.wrapper {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform-origin: top left;
  top: 100vh;
  height: 100vw;
  width: 100vh;
  position: absolute;
}
```