# HTML5 video on full screen rotaate the screen like on youtube in mobile device using jquery / javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, mobile, html5-video

I have a html5 custom video player, now I would like on clicking the full-screen icon on mobile to rotate the screen to landscape and vice versa as in youtube.

Here is my HTML

```
  <div id="video-block">
    <video class="video_player" id="player" width="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
      <source src="INPUT VIDEO URL HERE"/>
      Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag.  Use a better browser!
    </video>
    <button onclick="goFullscreen('player'); return false">
      View Fullscreen!
    </button>
 </div>
```

Here is js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // rotate function

    function rotateVideoPlayer() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        var height = $(window).height();

        $("#video-block").width(0);
        $("#video-block").height(0);

        console.log(width, height);
        // document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0
        if (width > height) {
            console.log("landscape");
            $("#video-block").width(width);
            $("#video-block").height(width * 9 / 16);


            $("#video-block").css("left", 0 + "px");
            $("#video-block").removeClass("rotated");

        } else {

            console.log("portrait");
            $("#video-block").width(height);
            $("#video-block").height(height * 9 / 16);


            $("#video-block").css("left", width - (width - height * 9 / 16) / 2 + "px");
            $("#video-block").addClass("rotated");
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0

        }
    }


    $('#btn').on('click', function(){
        rotateVideoPlayer();
        var element = document.getElementById('videocontainer');
        if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
            element.mozRequestFullScreen();
        } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
            element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
        }
    })
});
```

css

```
#video-block.rotated{
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -o-transform:rotate(90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(90deg);
  transform:rotate(90deg);
}
```

Unfortunately, my solution is not working as expected, there is a full screen but rotation is not working properly as on youtube.

Can someone help me to solve this problem? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: Not getting any ideas. But, maybe [this](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-screen-orientation-api-uses-javascript-to-rotate-the-screen-89639/) article might help. It's about the screen orientation.

Comment: @RandomCOSMOS thanks I will check

Comment: It's not clear under which circumstances you want to rotate: When the `<div>` ratio changes? When the screen changes orientation? Why not use [media queries to detect landscape/portrait orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation) and specify which CSS to apply in either case?

Comment: can you share screenshot of what you get with your code  ?

Comment: @Tuckbros I solved the problem but I am not happy with it its, because I am just rotating the video player, there is a lot of problem with different devices

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207008/how-do-i-lock-the-orientation-to-portrait-mode-in-a-iphone-web-application) help ?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini I tried all of them, i just came up with my own solution close to that , combination of css na js, on click I just rotate the videoplayer and change the width and height of a player accordingly , and force the orientation to landscape , it works but not pure full screen , there is a lot to be done to make it perfect , I HATE IPHONE

Comment: _I HATE IPHONE_  I understand you ..

Comment: @SimoneRossaini there are too many complications with ios safari it reminds me a lot with Explorer :(  check my other thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61751980/media-error-formats-not-supported-or-sources

Answer (score 9):

You can use `screen.orientation.lock('landscape')` to enable `landscape` once you are entering full-screen mode. It works for android only.

As there are some limitations on iOS for enabling full-screen mode, it's better to use default behaviours for videos on iOS as youtube does.

```js
$(function() {

  function makeLandscape() {
    // this works on android, not iOS
    if (screen.orientation && screen.orientation.lock) {
      screen.orientation.lock('landscape');
    }
  }

  $(document).on('click', '#btn', function() {
    var element = document.getElementById('video-container');
    if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      element.mozRequestFullScreen();
      makeLandscape();
    } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
      element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      makeLandscape();
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<div id="video-container">
  <video class="video_player" id="player" width="100%" autoplay="autoplay" playsinline="">
          <source src="https://wp-iframe.videomill.co/vpaidexamples/videos//vmerce.mp4" />
          Your browser does not support the HTML5 video tag. Use a better browser!
        </video>
  <button id="btn">
          View Fullscreen!
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: What about iPhone ios?

Comment: What about iPhone ios? and u need to provide your code here not the only link to jsfiddle, please test your solution on iPhone ios, and you will see that our solution is not working, I provided 300 bounties meaning that it's not simple as you think, remember Full-screen API not supported in iPhone ios

Comment: Please refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: you can rotate the content like mentioned in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856013/rotate-all-html-element-whole-page-90-degree-with-css. 
But even there are limitations on iOS for hiding toolbar, and full-screen mode enabling.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this answer? It's the closest thing there is to a cross-platform solution. iOS Safari is well known to be a crappy non-standards-compliant browser and the best thing you can do with it is hope the default behavior works.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, You have just not provided correct ID in the video player, Instead of ***id="player"*** provide ***id="video-block*"**, That is the reason why rotation CSS is not being applied. In below mentioned Tag

```
<video class="video_player" id="player" width="100%" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">enter code here
```

Comment: typing error but u understand the idea, and the problem is known to most developers, by the way, that does not solve the problem, check the demo and come with the solution