# Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5-video, http-live-streaming

I am using [media player js](https://www.mediaelementjs.com/) for my video, I am trying to play hls and dash video format in both ios and android.
Here is what I have so far.

Live demo code pen: [live demo](https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/JjYLvVe)

HTML

```
<div class="video">
   <video id="player1" muted autoplay controls preload="none">
```

data - quality = "SD" >

Here is JS

```
$('video').mediaelementplayer({
    features: ['playpause', 'current', 'progress', 'duration', 'volume', 'fullscreen', 'quality'],
    stretching: "responsive",
    enableAutosize: false,
    startVolume: 0.5,
    success: function(mediaElement, domObject) {
        mediaElement.setVolume(0.5);
        console.log(mediaElement);
    }
});
```

Now when I check on a mobile device **(ANDROID)** I get the following error:

```
Media error: Format(s) not supported or source(s) not found
```

[image]

**

> NOTE: on iPhone, everything is okay problem is with an android device

**

What do I need to do to solve this problem? any help or suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: i try your code (not code pen but this) and work with phone, possible in codepen is different video?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini did you try with android? on iphone its okay

Comment: yes i try with my samsung s8 - [Screen](https://ibb.co/26BcCn5)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini my bad , the mp4 video works fine , but I need to play hls file , I have updated the link , here is the demo https://codepen.io/makumba/pen/JjYLvVe

Comment: Try to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388135/how-to-play-html5-video-play-m3u8-on-mobile-and-desktop/23388308#23388308)

Comment: @simone solved the problem, it was about hls file not having the right codec'

Comment: Perfect ;)! Answer your question for community.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference about this error, make sure u have the right hls files with the right codecs , here is tutorial on how to convert mp4 to hls files , the right way

```
https://docs.peer5.com/guides/production-ready-hls-vod/
```