# Javascript - Prevent full screen when rotate a device on mobile

Tags: javascript, video

I'd like to prevent a html video full screen when rotate a device as landscape.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 video on full screen rotaate the screen like on youtube in mobile device using jquery / javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61469628/html5-video-on-full-screen-rotaate-the-screen-like-on-youtube-in-mobile-device-u)

Comment: No I'm going to prevent auto full screen when rotate a device.

Comment: http://www.mediaelementjs.com/
The video in this page doesn't go to full screen in any case on mobile device. I want like this.