# Change page orientation for a specific WordPress page to use it on TV

Tags: wordpress

I turned my TV physically to Potrait, now every webpage is turned with the TV. I want to turn the webpage to potrait so it would be readable.

Possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rotate all html element (whole page) 90 degree with CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35856013/rotate-all-html-element-whole-page-90-degree-with-css)

Comment: You may need to tell your Operating System that your TV should be in portrait mode. Here are the steps for Windows: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-rotate-screen-windows-10